# Ionic servce - http://localhost:8100/home

Tags: ionic-framework

I am a beginner for ionic framework.

May I ask when i type ionic serve, ionic app doesn't show app screen but it showed "Ready to create an app? Start with ionic UI component". I have seen from youtube tutorial it suppose to show up mobile like screen.

Appreciate someone can help to verify my query please. thanks.

Comment: sorry typo error on heading: " ionic serve"

Comment: You can still edit your question using the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63136398/edit) below the question.

Comment: I think it is working as expected. It is showing the default page for a starter. Please go through the docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/serve.

Comment: Your tutorial seems to be outdated. Please Go for latest tutorials. it is working as expected. if you want to have a mobile look go to your console by pressing `f12` or right clicking the view and change it to mobile.

Comment: Thank you will try it out. Appreciate a lot for the reply :)

Comment: do you mean the splash screen? 
Anyway, the splash screen is available only on fisical device or emulator, so 
it's perfectly normal dont see the splash on browser (ionic serve)